# capacitor: telemetry Could not obtain unique app identifier

Tags: angular, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm interested in Ionic and studying it now. I use capacitor to generate the android apps, but there is always this error and failed:

```
[capacitor] 2021-12-30T07:54:16.098Z capacitor:android:run Invoking ./gradlew with args: [ 'assembleDebug' ]
[capacitor] × Running Gradle build - failed!
[capacitor] 2021-12-30T07:54:16.211Z capacitor:telemetry Could not obtain unique app identifier
[capacitor] [error]
```

I assume this is because my app ID and app name is not unique, so I changed capacitor.config.ts into this:

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.course.ionicangularhenry',
  appName: 'Henry Test',
  webDir: 'www',
  bundledWebRuntime: false
};

export default config;
```

After that, I deleted the whole android folder and execute:

```
> ionic capacitor add android
> ionic capacitor run android
```

But I still have the same error. What could be the problem? Please help.

**UPDATE**

This is the result of ionic info

```
[WARN] Error loading @capacitor/ios package.json: Error: Cannot find module '@capacitor/ios/package'

       Require stack:
       - C:\Users\henry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\project\index.js
       - C:\Users\henry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\index.js
       - C:\Users\henry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\index.js
       - C:\Users\henry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\bin\ionic

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.3 (C:\Users\henry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.0.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.0.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.0.4
   @angular/cli                  : 13.0.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 5.0.3

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 3.3.3
   @capacitor/android : 3.3.3
   @capacitor/core    : 3.3.3
   @capacitor/ios     : not installed

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : 1.5.0

System:

   NodeJS : v16.13.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 8.1.2
   OS     : Windows 10
```

And this is the result of npx cap doctor

```
Capacitor Doctor   

Latest Dependencies:       

  @capacitor/cli: 3.3.3    
  @capacitor/core: 3.3.3   
  @capacitor/android: 3.3.3
  @capacitor/ios: 3.3.3    

Installed Dependencies:    

  @capacitor/ios: not installed
  @capacitor/cli: 3.3.3        
  @capacitor/core: 3.3.3       
  @capacitor/android: 3.3.3
```

Comment: run command `npm install @capacitor/android` and than `npx cap add android`. 
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android

Comment: I've just done that. Still the same error

Comment: Looks like some configuration issue: Can you please run command `ionic info` and `npx cap doctor` add output of both commands to your question.

Comment: I've added it @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: found a solution? @HenryGunawan

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet